# Excel: Move Duplicate Customer's Employees to Empty Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I pull a report of customers with their contact info sometimes I have duplicate lines when they have multiple email addresses on file. I have been trying to find a good way to move the second or third email to the empty space next to the first email. I have included a screenshot of a sample date set so you can understand what I mean.

I was thinking I might have to write up an if-then statement saying if the IDnumber is duplicated then pull colC values into colD values, or E values if D is full. I have been getting lost in the execution though.

Thank you greatly for any help and guidance.

[image: sample]

Comment: You'll need VBA as formulas won't "move" cell values around. By itself I don't think IF-THEN statements are powerful enough to perform your ask. You'll need to use newer Excel LAMBDA formulas, but these would create a separate table based on the original data (leaving the original intact). Another option is Power Query built into excel (output still goes to a separate table).

Comment: I am fine with using a lambda statement and creating a new table. I am somewhat familiar with lambda's; even if I have to run my data through a python program to execute. I am still new to everything though and am hung up on how to write out a command for the moving of the emails at all.

Comment: Is your worksheet always sorted by ID#?

Comment: The ID numbers will always come bunched together, just not in numerical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think there's a way to use Index/Match/Offset here, but here's an alternative method which **assumes you have the worksheet sorted (grouped together) by ID and you never have more than 3 email addresses per person**.

I created a helper column (Column C) which is basically counting how many IDs you have from the top of the sheet to the current row. It's concatenating some text to it.

Cell C2 formula:

```
=CONCAT("Email_",COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2))
```

Then the following formulas are basically a manual offset...

Cell E2 formula (comparing one row below to column header):

```
=IF(C3=$E$1,D3,"")
```

Cell F2 formula (comparing two rows below to column header):

```
=IF(C4=$F$1,D4,"")
```

Drag down your formulas and output would appear as:

| ID | Name | IdRank | Email | Email_2 | Email_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Amy | Email_1 | amy1 | newAmy |  |
| 1234 | Amy | Email_2 | newAmy |  |  |
| 5678 | Mike | Email_1 | michael |  |  |
| 9123 | Bob | Email_1 | bobert |  |  |
| 8912 | Fred | Email_1 | freddie | flintsone | effedman |
| 8912 | Fred | Email_2 | flintsone |  |  |
| 8912 | Fred | Email_3 | effedman |  |  |

Obviously this method doesn't move anything, but after all is said and done, you could create a copy of the sheet, replace all formulas with values, and then sort and keep where helper Column C = Email_1.

I would recommend looking for better answers, as this one has too many assumptions; however, it could be a bandaid solution for the time being.